# How Databinding is implemented/handled under the hood

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Just for sake of curiosity, i am investigating on how databindigs is implemented in the Winform application.

For example i have one gridview (2 columns) with a DataSource associated (a list of touple of strings) then when i change the selected row in the form i would update value in two textbox (one textbox per column).

I have learned that i can achieve this with Databindings and all seems to work fine (e.g. below) :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Tuple<string, string>> _datasource = new List<Tuple<string, string>>(new Tuple<string, string>[] {
        new Tuple<string, string> ( "C1 First row" , "C2 First row"),
        new Tuple<string, string> ( "C1 Second row" , "C2 Second row"),
        new Tuple<string, string> ( "C1 Third row" , "C2 Third row"),
        new Tuple<string, string> ( "C1 Fourth row" , "C2 Fourth row")
    });

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.grdTest.DataSource = _datasource;


        this.txtC1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _datasource, "Item1");
        this.txtC2.DataBindings.Add("Text", _datasource, "Item2");
    }
}
```

What is not clear to me is how the framework keep track of the fact that the row is changed (and which is the selected row).
In the databinding statement i don't specifify which is the table and the datasource (a simple list) surely does not keep track of the selected item.

So the way used to get things done is completly obsucre to me.
Please can someone clarify that aspect to me?

Comment: [CurrencyManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.currencymanager) class. You can use a BindingList, or a custom class that implements [IBindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist), to also allow ListChanged notifications (so you can add rows to a List objects that can support it).

Comment: Thanks CurrencyManager is definitely a misleading name (Microsoft could have chosen a better one) but after a little reasearch about it, now is much more clear how it works.